# PHP array iteration issues

Tags: php, arrays

Hey, so I have this array, called $files (var_dump()ed):

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["_c"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["title"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["_v"]=>
        string(9) "blueprint"
      }
      ["src"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["_v"]=>
        string(20) "blueprint/screen.css"
      }
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["_c"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["title"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["_v"]=>
        string(7) "general"
      }
      ["src"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["_v"]=>
        string(11) "general.css"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but when I:

```
foreach($files as $file){
    // etc.
}
```

I get an `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Any ideas? thanks.

Comment: It is not possible. Give the complete code that reproduces this issue.

Comment: My guess a non array/object has clobbered `$files`.

Comment: @zerkms http://pastebin.com/9w1XUu0P

Comment: @nomaD: it is not **complete** code. Add all variables definitions to that snippet so we can just copy-paste it, run and see the issue.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/rCp6EbPn line 114 is the one that gives an error

Comment: http://pastebin.com/rCp6EbPn line 109 will return an empty string or null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahhh. I see what you're doing. You are quite correct that for the ***css*** key you get `file` tags and thus a valid array:

```
    <css>
        <file>
            <title>blueprint</title>
            <src>blueprint/screen.css</src>
        </file>
        <file>
            <title>general</title>
            <src>general.css</src>
        </file>
    </css>
```

But how about when the ***js*** key comes up?

```
    <js>

    </js>
```

Sure enough, there is no `file` key, there is no array, and PHP chokes.

You may want to throw a

```
if (!isset($files['file'])) continue;
```

in there.

Comment: The key 'file' is actually brought in from the xml file. On line 105 you can see I go through it as an array, just not in a while() loop. var_dump()ing `$files` after line 113 (aka `$files['file']`) gives me the array in the original question. See: http://pastebin.com/qvGbX4K2

Comment: I misread that. Edited with a completely different (and must more tangible) explanation.

Comment: Ok now this is REALLY doing my head in, I just added in another while loop before the one that breaks: http://pastebin.com/nhJrJCT6
They both work fine, but also give me warnings at the same time!

Comment: Yeah it turns out the error was from the js array (which now that I think about it wouldn't exist because there were no files in the js area). Problem solved 100% thanks a lot mate! :D